# Autocomplete Google Places sample

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to run the Google Place Code Sample, but I am not able to do it.

I am receiving error messages like:

> Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}

I added my Google Map V2 ApiKey to the Manifest, and signed the app with the right certificate, so it seems that the key could be here:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
```

I am not sure what is supposed to be in the `clientId` slot, and there is not too much info out there. Just other people with the same problem but without solution.

By the way if somebody wants to take a look to the complete code it is here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/issues/3

Comment: Have you filled in your details in the consent screen of the developer's console? A project name and email address is the minimum.

Comment: Hi, the problem was the right API to register the app is hide in the new Google Developers Console fashion design.

Comment: I suggest you not implement autocomplete API because Google will be shutting this down soon. Look here: http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/24/google-will-restrict-access-to-its-autocomplete-api-on-august-10-asks-developers-to-use-custom-search-engine/

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Noted. However, the Places Autocomplete Api and The Search AutocompleteApi are different. The article talks of the Search AutoComplete Api.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was mistaken.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer - post the answer separately instead. It's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 5):

This error can be caused by not enabling the `Places API for Android` in your `Google Developer Console` (This is different from the regular `Places API`).

It can also be caused if you set your API key using the old 'maps' identifier instead of `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY`, when adding the google meta-data to your application manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really helps me as i am using com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY so, it getting TIMEOUT error After changing it to com.google.android.geo.API_KEY solved my error.

Comment: Works with the "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" identifier! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, I also was using the old com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY, you saved me lot of time !